# SSAS Average in Hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I spent quite some time looking for a solution here but I haven't been able to find a result

My current MDX code looks like this

```
SUM([Measures].[Absolute Position])/SUM([Measures].[Result Count])
```

For clarification "Result Count" is a value in my table that counts each record. I put it in there with the intent to be able to do a simple sum/count formula.

Here is the result in my cube 
[Cube Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw3G1.png)

In the pic the average is correct at the lowest level of my hierarchy but at the month/quarter/year levels it breaks. I initially thought it might have something to do with null values but I haven't found any success going down that road. Any help to get the correct average to show up on higher levels of a hierarchy would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Added a pic with the math. [Cube with Math](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00B6Q.png)

Comment: Can you put Absolute Position and Result Count measures into the PivotTable and include a new screenshot? And can you provide the proper math for the Feb subtotal?

Comment: Posted above. Interesting that the absolute results don't seem to be aggregating to the month correctly. The Feb "Absolute Position" sum should be 7,198,957. This means I have something new to look for! Thank you for asking the good question.

Comment: @RichardGwilliam Feb is showing 5.17 which is (799884.11 / 154865) .... so what should Feb be showing instead of 5.17 ? Lets say it should be showing X ... then also can you tell us how X is calulated i.e. if X=(Y/Z) what are the values of Y and Z ?